# How to inspect vars / persist value tooltip window in PowerShell ISE?

Tags: powershell-extensions

After running a script in Sitecore PowerShell Extensions version 6.4.0.16859, I can hover over a variable to inspect its contents. However, it contains values that overflow out of my screen. I would like to scroll or have some form of control over the popup, but moving the cursor over the tooltip causes it to disappear.

[image: hover tooltip in PowerShell ISE]

What are some good options for inspecting such values?

Comment: You can open the immediate window and then start to inspect the variables using power shell commands.